# Number of ways of selecting N items with K types where each type must have $n_i$ items where $\sum_i n_i = N$

Tags: combinatorics

So let's suppose we have $N$ items. We have $K$ types of item.

For each type of item we denote the number of that type of item as  $n_i$ and for completeness $(1 <= i <= K)$ with the constraint that

$\sum_i n_i = N$

How many combinations are there of this?

So the simplest case is where $K =1$ where clearly the number of combinations is $1$.

With $K=2$, you take $N\choose{n_1}$ or $N\choose{n_2}$ because the number of combinations of $n_1$ items in N items is the same as the number of combinations of $N-n_1$ items in $N$ items.

However, I come across a problem when I get to $K>2$. I don't know what to make of it at all and find myself very stuck at this. With $K=3$, $N=3$ and $n_i = 1 ,~\forall n_i$ then we end up with, if we label our types of item A, B and C

ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA

Now from this I observe that for A, I placed it in a set position, of which there are N positions and then went through the combinations of the rest of it which comes out as

${{N}\choose{n_1}} {{N-1}\choose{n_2}} = 3\times 2 = 6$ combinations

Now doing the same again but with $K=3$,  $N=4$, $n_1 = 2$, $n_2 = 1$, $n_3 =1$ we get

AABC
AACB
ACBA
ABCA
BCAA
CBAA
BAAC
CAAB
ABAC
ACAB
BACA
CABA

and the way I have done it this time is to place the two A's in set positions and then use the combinations of the others: so

${N\choose{2}} {{N-2}\choose{1}} = 6 \times 2 = 12$ combinations

So can this generalise for say $n_1 = P, ~n_2 = Q, ~n_3 = R$ with $N=P+Q+R$:

${{N}\choose{n_1}}{{N-n_1}\choose{n_2}}{{N-n_1-n_2}\choose{n_3}}$

and does that generalise to $K$ types by:

$\Pi_k{{{N-\sum_{i=0}^{i=k-1}n_i}\choose{n_k}}}$ where $n_0 = 0$?

I'm not really equipped with the skills to prove this, as I did not focus on combinatorics when I did my maths degree I did pure maths and mechanics/fluid mechanics instead, but that's my best effort and I haven't found an answer elsewhere

Thank you for listening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is correct, but it can be explained in a simpler way. In particular your final formula has an undesirable look.

Assume that the $n_i$ objects of type $T_i$ $(1\leq i\leq K)$ are marked with numbers from $1$ to $n_i$. If we also look at the numbers we can linearly order the totally $N$ objects in $N!$ ways. Now in *your* counting the numbers do not play a rôle. This means that the $n_i!$ permutations of the objects of type $T_i$ among themselves in such an ordering do not lead to  new "combinations", and this for each $i\in[K]$ separately. It follows that your number of "combinations" is given by
$${N!\over n_1!\>n_2!\>\ldots\>n_K!}\ ,$$
and this is the way the final formula should be written.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! I'm kind of immensely surprised that i managed it frankly. I was doing it from very bare basics. Can you just explain something a little further, as i am really not good at combinatorics and don't have an intuitive grasp on it - why would you divide by those $n_i!$s? I appreciate no short answer may be able to happen here, so if this needs to be discussed or looked up by myself somewhere else, i fully appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: these are *multinomial coefficients*. You can express them more compactly as $$\frac{N!}{\prod n_i!}$$ which shows their origin: you can rearrange the $N$ items in $N!$ ways, but then for each $i$ you divide by $n_i!$ because the order of items of the same type doesn't matter.

Comment: So, can you clarify why the order of the items of the same type doesn't matter (which I agree on and understand) means that you divide by $n_i!$? I agree that it works but am struggling to understand **why** it works intuitively. Thank you for your help

Comment: @JamesRobinson, there are $n!$ ways to order $n$ items because there are $n$ choices for the first one, $n-1$ choices for the second one, etc.

Comment: I understand that bit, the bit that i don't understand is that if i have N items, then there are N! combinations of those items. Now if i take M < N of those items, i understand that there are M! combinations of those M items. Now, if those M items are totally indistinguishable, then any one of those combinations is the same as any other. What i don't understand is why that means that the no.of combinations for those N items (where M are of a different type and indistinguishable) is now N!/M!, are you saying it's because given an ordering of those M items there are (N-M) choices etc?

Comment: @JamesRobinson, suppose that the $M$ items were originally distinguishable. Then after shuffling the $N$ items you decide to spray-paint the $M$ items to be indistinguishable. This creates an *equivalence relation* on the arrangements, where each equivalence class contains $M!$ arrangements because it collapses $M!$ orderings of the $M$ items into one set of indices at which you find spray-painted objects.

Comment: I have found another way to think about it that makes intuitive sense to me and it comes off the back of your explanation. (I'm hoping it's not wrong)

You can look at arranging the M items in the N items as choosing M items from N items, and then the combinations of the rest of the items left over are (M-N)!, so ${N\choose M}$*$(M-N)!$ = $\frac{M!}{N!}$. Thank you so much for your help Peter, I'm happy with that explanation now :)